# React component not receiving props

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I wanted to add a loader to my component until some function finished. I"ll show code because I don't know how to explain

```
 render(): JSX.Element {
    if (!this.state.loaded) {
        return  <Spinner />
    }
    return (<ComponentStuffToShowAfterLoaded>
               <SubComponent type={this.state.type} /> //edited here since causing confusing, just an example
            <ComponentStuffToShowAfterLoaded>)
}
```

The sub component's componentWillReceiveProps is never called. I hope this makes sense, but I'll try to clarify if needed.

Comment: @JMadelaine i don't think so.

Comment: @JMadelaine Sorry, that was just an example, please ignore, that's not actually how i"m passing the props.
 <Component type={this.props.type} />
Is a correct example

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing in the above code is assigning the parents props to a prop called `prop` (wow that's a confusing sentence).  Instead, you want to spread the props directly so that the child component receives each prop individually

```
<SubComponent {...this.props} />
```

So if you have a prop called `name`, your `SubComponent` will receive a prop called `name` (`this.props.name` in `SubComponent`), instead of a prop called `props` and that containing `props.name`(`this.props.props.name`).